# OpenCV Remove smaller contours

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, contour, edge-detection

I want to identify and extract the contour of the largest leaf of the following image using OpenCV and C++.

[image]

I applied Canny edge detector to the image and got the following result.

```
    Canny(img_src, img_edge_detected, 20, 60, 3);
```

[image]

Now I want to extract the largest contour (largest leaf) form the image and draw the contour line, but the problem here is the edge line of the largest leaf is not continuous. So I looked in to dialate and morphological close but using those functions I couldn't get a good result to extract the area. Is there any way to get the largest contour in such image?

**Note that** here I cannot use template matching or any masking kind of things because my final intention is to built a system where a user can upload an image and get the species of the plant. So the system doesn't have any prior idea about the shape of the leaf that user is going to upload.

Please tell me how to find and draw the largest contour here if it is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to cluster by color first? At least for this example it could work. Working only with contour here looks quite impossible to me since they aren't separated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.I didn't try to use clustering I just tried to use edge detection, can you please point me to a good example of clustering I'm new to image processing.

Comment: As @Micka says, this is really a segmentation problem, you're jumping in to contours too quickly. You could start by assuming that the leaf of interest is central in the image and maybe use watershed or floodfill to segment it.

Comment: Can you please explain bit how to do the segmentation or clustering here ?

Comment: Take a look at the [watershed features in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) to start with.

Comment: It seems that watershed is not working for this purpose. Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: @RogerRowland the link was broken. Maybe [Image Segmentation with Watershed Algorithm](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html) is useful.

Answer (score 0):

cant you use hsv color threshoding to track only that leaf and then you can straight away use minmaxloc function to get the area of the largest contour.just an idea try doing it like that.it will work.good luck

Answer (score 0):

Same thing i will do in java please convert it into c++, here BGR to convert HSV then after apply the combination of the yellow, green and brown with specified range and simply perfom bitwise or operation. it will be give to you not zero pixles using opencv function Core.findNonZero(Mat src, Mat dst);

```
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV, 4);

    //Yellow
    Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(25, 80, 80), new Scalar(36, 255, 255), yellow);
    //Green
    Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(37, 80, 80), new Scalar(70, 255, 255), green);
    //Brown
    Core.inRange(mHSV, new Scalar(10, 80, 80), new Scalar(30, 200, 200), brown);

    // logical OR mask
    Core.bitwise_or(yellow, green, green);
    Core.bitwise_or(green, brown, mask);

    Imgproc.dilate(mask, mask, new Mat());

    // Find non zero pixels
    pts = Mat.zeros(mask.size(), mask.type());
    Core.findNonZero(mask, pts);

    return mask;
```